# Can I have "Insert worksheet" tab on the left before used Excel worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'd like to have the “New sheet” tab all the way to the left,
so others will readily see the tab to start a new sheet. 
Yet, keep the scroll bar to the right. 
Like this:
[image: mockup of “New sheet” tab on left]

Answer (score 0):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets(1)
End Sub
```